# Electrostatics and two electric charges

Tags: electrostatics

How can two identical metallic objects have the same but opposite charges (one loses electrons and one gains electrons) when we know that metals have the ability to lose electrons only?

Comment: Yes of course it's true. Metal will only loose the electrons.

Take it in this way. A have 5 protons and 5 electrons and B have 10 protons and 10 electrons. Both are electrically neutral. Now by any of the method you transferred 2 electrons from B to A . Now A have 7 electron and 5 proton which is 2 electrons more than neutral phase (i.e  A is having $-2e$ charge) and B will have 8 electrons and 10 protons, 2 electrons less than neutral phase (i.e. B is having $+2e$ charge). Hence A have $-2e$ charge and B have $+2e$ charge which are both equal and opposite.

Comment: I think you've been suffering a confusion that any student in beginning often faces but I bet when you'll understand it you'll think this to be very funny. 

First of all read the comment twice and thrice and think it over again and again. If you still don't get it, check this http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-2/Charging-by-Induction

Comment: They are two (metallic balls )

Comment: Of course metals do gain electron. Remember every element in periodic table have Electron Gain Enthalpy (and transition metals are also included). I think you need a bit of research. But in nut shell let me tell you that metals do gain electron. Please don't confuse from my statement that I had made ("Yes of course it's true. Metal will only loose the electrons"). They also gain electron. Check the link.

Comment: So the example you had give is in an metal that gain electrons ( transition element) and one that gain electrons and that it was written in our book

Comment: Please answer me simple to not be confused

Answer (score 1):

In solids the outer electrons of the molecules composing them [form bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure).

Electrons exist in what are called [Fermi level bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level), the energy levels they occupy are practically continuous and little  energy is needed for an electron to be removed from the surface, particularly in metals.

Usually the material is neutral. If an electron is missing from a band, then a positive resultant charge appears due to the positive charges of the nuclei of the solid, and it is called a *hole* , as it is localized within the band.

If a lot of electrons are removed from a metal ball then the ball will be positive because of the holes, and a metal ball can accept many electrons because the band structure is continuous and the electron can occupy extra energy levels in that continuum.

In other words, a metal that loses an electron gains a hole, which is positive because the value of one electron is missing from neutralizing the charges of the nuclei.

In order to charge a metal ball  a voltage has to be applied. [This circuit](http://www.tpub.com/neets/book2/3b.htm) of a capacitor

[image: capacitor charge]

> At the instant the switch is closed, the positive terminal of the battery extracts an electron from the bottom conductor. The negative terminal of the battery forces an electron into the top conductor. At this same instant an electron is forced into the top plate of the capacitor and another is pulled from the bottom plate. Thus, in every part of the circuit a clockwise DISPLACEMENT of electrons occurs simultaneously.

The forced electrons occupy the extra energy levels ( over neutrality) that exist quantum mechanically in the conduction bands of the metal. If one makes the plates of the capacitor two balls, and cuts them off, one will have positive charge from the holes and the other negative from the excess electrons. The energy has been supplied by the DC power source.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer to the question. That a metal can loose electrons is not difficult to understand, the difficulty is for a metal to GAIN electrons.

Comment: @Sofia  ok, I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

A battery produces the effect you ask about. It removes electrons from the metal that represents the positive pole (cathode) and brings them to the metal that represents the negative pole (anode). For doing this operation, energy is invested.
But, you'd better read how that is done in Wikipedia under the title "Battery (electricity)".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(electricity)#Principle_of_operation

Good luck,
Sofia

Answer (score 1):

You said metals have the ability to lose electrons only. This is not true. Metals can also gain electrons.

So suppose you have two conductors, A and B, where each one is electrically netrual (that is, each one has the same number of electrons as it does protons). Now imagine that some electrons are transferred from A to B. Then A has lost electrons and so it has more protons than electrons and therefore has a positive charge. By contrast, B has gained electrons, and so it has more electrons than protons and so it has a negative charge. In fact, they will have opposite charges of the same magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing chemistry and physics.

In chemistry you may have learnt that when metals react, they give up electrons (the are oxidized). That is because there are usually a small number of electrons in the outermost orbit of the atom, and when these are released the atom is left with a very stable electron configuration.

But when you are looking at a metallic object that is charged, the additional electrons are not bound to an individual atom like they would be in a chemical reaction: instead, they "float around" inside the metal, as part of the sea of electrons ("electron gas" is a term that is sometimes used) that provide the metal with its conductivity.

This electron gas can have a few extra electrons in it, or it can be short a few; the metal can therefore be either positively or negatively charged.